# Coefficient of Variations?

Tags: statistics, histogram, std, variance

I have a list of values incrementing exponentially. I was asked to have multiple Coefficent of variations from them. You might agree with me that CV is only for the whole set of numbers and dividing the set of numbers into subgroups and calculating a CV for each subgroup seems unreasonable. Would there be any statistical idea behind multiple CVs and if there is, how histogram can be made by the CVs, I mean what would the bins of the historgram. I appreciate the answers in advance

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you - it does not make sense to me to calculate multiple CVs for one dataset *unless* there's some inferential reason for doing so.

That being said, there might actually be a reason for considering sub-groups of a dataset.  In the field of Statistics, context is everything.  My first thought is to ask your colleague why they want you do proceed that way.  Maybe there's a good reason, maybe they don't have as full a grasp of stats as you do, regardless, it should be an enlightening conversation to have.

If you do decide to go this route, here's some R code that might help (R is great - flexible, powerful, and free)

```
# first, simulating some fake data (100 values of measurement & group for 10 groups)
x <- rnorm(100, mean=10, sd=1)
group <- sample(LETTERS[1:10], 100, replace=T)

# first few values of each
head(data.frame(x, group))
          x group
1 10.778480     F
2  9.274193     B
3  9.639143     G
4  9.080369     I
5 10.727895     D
6 10.850306     G

# this is the part you'd actually need...
# calculating the sd & avgs for each group
sds <- tapply(x, group, sd)
avgs <- tapply(x, group, mean)

# then the cv
cvs <- sds/avgs

cvs
         A          B          C          D          E          F          G          H          I          J 
0.07859528 0.07570556 0.09370247 0.12552468 0.08897856 0.11044543 0.10947615 0.10323379 0.08908262 0.09729945 

# and if you want a histogram, R makes it pretty easy
hist(cvs)
```